# How to get container for Autofac for WebAPI2?

Tags: c#, ninject, inversion-of-control, autofac

In Ninject I can get object needed for interface by using class `WebContainerManager`

Ninject definition:

```
 var logManager = new LogManagerAdapter(); 
 container.Bind<ILogManager>().ToConstant(logManager);
```

Ninject usage:

```
var log = WebContainerManager.Get<ILogManager>().GetLog(typeof(WebApiApplication));
```

**My question is how to do the same in Autofac, to get needed class for interface?**

UPDATE 1: Im using WebAPi 2, not MVC.

Comment: FWIW, this is the Service Locator anti-pattern, and is not generally a good idea. you should be using constructor or property injection instead.

Comment: Probably, I just wanted to do something quickly ... and was not able to find quick solution:). Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 10):

If you need access to Autofac container from the class that was resolved by Autofac itself, then you can specify dependency on IComponentContext that is automatically provided by Autofac.

Example:

```
public void SomeComponent(IComponentContext context)
{
   this.context = context;
}
...
// somewhere inside SomeComponent
context.Resolve<ILogManager>();
```

If your code is running inside ASP.Net environment, then you most probably set its DependencyResolver, thus you can always access it like:

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILogManager>();
```

but as it is already mentioned in other comments, Service Locator is an anti-pattern that should be avoided.

In order to integrate autofac container with standard MVC dependency resolution mechanism you need to:

- install Autofac.Mvc5 nuget package
- set DependencyResolver with the following code

  `var container = builder.Build();
  DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));`

And in case you don't mind having explicit dependency on Autofac in your application code you can access global Autofac resolver reference the same way you use Ninject WebContainerManager:

```
var log = AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.Resolve<ILogManager>().GetLog(typeof(WebApiApplication));
```

Comment: DI is not the solution which I need in my question.

Comment: Line: `var x = (ILogManager)MVC.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(ILogManager));` gives null :). Like this is not seeing my autofac container but it works:)

Comment: I assumed that you already have DependencyResolution integration with Autofac in place. I updated answer with details on how to do that.

Comment: @P.K. I have updated my answer to show how to access global Autofac container reference, just the same way you use Ninject WebContainerManager (although I do not advise to use it that way, but that was your question).

Comment: AutofacDependencyResolver is unknown (I have autofac 2 libs attached and autofaq forking instance). No option to add any namespace. Anyway I solved the problem by injection via contructor:), but I still curious how to do it:). Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @P.K. AutofacDependencyResolver comes with Autofac.Mvc5 nuget package. So, you solved it by injecting IComponentContext to your component as I showed in first example of my answer?

Comment: Thanks. I using Web API 2:) .... I know that probably I can add this package:) but any specific solution for Web API2:)?

Comment: For WebApi you need  Autofac.WebApi nuget package and set HttpConfiguration.DependencyResolver in similar way. But you should have probably already set it?

Comment: My DI container works:), I just want to get this container in code:). HttpConfiguration has no such method like DependencyResolver.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83991/discussion-between-vitaliy-tsvayer-and-p-k).

Answer (score 7):

You can create your builder.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Usually you're only interested in exposing the type
// via its interface:
builder.RegisterType<SomeType>().As<IService>();

// However, if you want BOTH services (not as common)
// you can say so:
builder.RegisterType<SomeType>().AsSelf().As<IService>();
```

Then you will be able to build your IoC:

```
IContainer Container = builder.Build();
```

And a simple example of How to get resource from container:

```
// Create the scope, resolve your IService,
// use it, then dispose of the scope.
using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
  var writer = scope.Resolve<IService>();
  writer.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Beautiful example and "How to start": http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/getting-started/

Comment: Still I have a problem with this, your Container is based on configuration via builder object. But I need the way to use it with existing configuration, in any part of code. Independly from configuration ... like my Ninject usage code...:)

Comment: @P.K. Could you please post here an example of your configuration ? Then I will try to clarify and will help you. ;) You can edit your main topic with your Autofac example/object registration.

Comment: In you code I changed `using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())` into  `using (var scope = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetRequestLifetimeScope())` to get container in code, and it works. Hopefully it ok:)

Comment: My problem was that I have Autofac configured... and suddenly in code I want to get class for interface defined in Autofac. In you exmaple you are using builder because you have acess to it. In my scenario, I had no access to builder, so I needed the way to get Container. Is it more clear?